# Historical OCR of .png in R

Tags: r, ocr

[image: WY Production Data]

I'm trying to OCR this .png of data, but i'm having trouble splitting the data into columns. Particularly in the WY Production Data I would like to split the Leases, companies, and Counties. This is a historical document and the formatting is a bit odd. The indentations change from page to page and I can't figure out how to write something that can account for the changes in indentation of company and lease except writing a separate code for each page and cropping specific portions. Below is what I have written in RStudio.

```
library(tesseract)
library(tidyverse)

eng <- tesseract("eng")
text <- tesseract::ocr("test_page_75_crop_table.png")
cat(text)

dataframe_test <- text %>%
  str_split(pattern = "\n") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  tibble(data = .)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to achieve a reasonable result with the following code with the OCR of the Word software :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(magick)

################################################
#### Step 1 : We convert the image to a PDF ####
################################################

path_PDF <- "D:\\temp2.pdf"
path_PNG <- "D:\\A09Yb.png"
path_Word <- "D:\\temp2.docx"

pdf(path_PDF, height = 16, width = 12)

im <- image_read(path_PNG)
plot(im)
dev.off()

####################################################################
#### Step 2 : We use the OCR of Word to convert the PDF to word ####
####################################################################
wordApp <- COMCreate("Word.Application")
wordApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
wordApp[["DisplayAlerts"]] <- FALSE

doc <- wordApp[["Documents"]]$Open(normalizePath(path_PDF), ConfirmConversions = FALSE)
doc$SaveAs2(path_Word)

##############################################################
#### Step 3 : We extract the table from the Word document ####
##############################################################

nb_Tables <- doc$tables()$count()
list_Table <- list()

for(l in 1 : nb_Tables)
{
  print(l)
  nb_Row <- doc$tables(l)$Rows()$Count()
  nb_Col <- doc$tables(l)$Columns()$Count()
  mat_Temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = nb_Row, ncol = nb_Col)
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Row)
  {
    for(j in 1 : nb_Col)
    {
      mat_Temp[i, j] <- tryCatch(doc$tables(l)$cell(i, j)$range()$text(), error = function(e) NA)
    }
  }
  
  list_Table[[l]] <- mat_Temp
}

list_Table

[[1]]
      [,1]                                                                                                        [,2]                              
 [1,] "FIELD\r\a"                                                                                                 "COUNTr\r\a"                      
 [2,] "HESI URIC.N OIL\r\a"                                                                                       "Na TRONa FRCNT\r\a"              
 [3,] "UNICN on.\rLEESES\rPc1SG\". SPRING CREEK\rSKELLY OIL\rTRUE\rLEZSES\rFCLECzr\rYULE CREEK O IL\rL \"SES\r\a" "NAIRONA\rC27311\rLANKER\rTER\r\a"
 [4,] NA                                                                                                          NA                                
 [5,] "CREEK\r\a"                                                                                                 "CROOK\r\a"                       
 [6,] "\tIN \tSHELL-SCHL'R ICHI\r\a"                                                                              NA                                
 [7,] "OCR\r\a"                                                                                                   ""                                
 [8,] "\r\a"                                                                                                      ""                                
 [9,] "GREET NCRTFERN\rLEASES\rPCM ELL neaNLcNEc LEZSES\r\a"                                                      "ICHT\rCONVERSE\r\a"              
[10,] "GIL \tGAS FUTURES LECSES\r\a"                                                                              "CEMPBELL\r\a"                    
[11,] ""                                                                                                          "CRCOK\r\a"                       
[12,] ""                                                                                                          "SkEETbATER\r\a"                  
      [,3]                         [,4]                     [,5]                  [,6]              [,7]             [,8]                    [,9]                  
 [1,] "\r\a"                       "\r\a"                   "\r\a"                "\r\a"            "\r\a"           "\r\a"                  "\r\a"                
 [2,] "\r\a"                       "\r\a"                   "33N\r\a"             "IRKS\r\a"        "30\r\a"         "938\r\a"               "\r\a"                
 [3,] "\r\a"                       "11\r21\r\a"             "3LN E4k CCYE\r\a"    "\r\a"            "388\r439\r\a"   "12, 040\r422\r502\r\a" "9. 632\r9,632\r\a"   
 [4,] NA                           NA                       "c3H\r\a"             "PDCY\r\a"        NA               NA                      NA                    
 [5,] "20\r\a"                     "\r\a"                   "IG5s\r\a"            "FhLS\rFN'LS\r\a" "EFPL\rBFPL\r\a" "135\r109\r\a"          "543 les 400\r3E6\r\a"
 [6,] "e scN 67k 5CN\r50N SES\r\a" NA                       NA                    NA                NA               NA                      NA                    
 [7,] NA                           NA                       NA                    NA                NA               NA                      NA                    
 [8,] "\r\a"                       "51N SEB\r\a"            "YhLS\r\a"            "EFPL\r\a"        "\r\a"           "2, 779\r\a"            "\r\a"                
 [9,] "\r\a"                       ""                       "PNLS\r\a"            "eFPt\r\a"        "231\r692\r\a"   "7, 153\r21, 450\r\a"   "\r\a"                
[10,] "\r\a"                       "Lc;ec\r12 52N\r\a"      "\r\a"                "TRKS\r\a"        "\r\a"           "561\r561\r\a"          "\r\a"                
[11,] "\r\a"                       "1960\r6EH\r\a"          "\r\a"                "\r\a"            "\r\a"           "\r\a"                  "697\r\a"             
[12,] "\r\a"                       "54B 6EH\r7 53N\r11\r\a" "BCSL hCSL\rFAIR\r\a" "\r\a"            "107\r\a"        "913\r3,325\r\a"        "522\r1. 219\r\a"     
      [,10]                                              [,11]                                             [,12] 
 [1,] "\r\a"                                             "\r\a"                                            NA    
 [2,] "183,274\r\a"                                      "12.910\r\a"                                      NA    
 [3,] "12,040 eco,\rfie,950\r21,01E\r122,004\r7.159\r\a" "9 ,632\r39 ,940\r20 ,449\r391 ,660\r\a"          NA    
 [4,] NA                                                 NA                                                NA    
 [5,] "\r\a"                                             "zye,03e\r206,219\r\a"                            "\r\a"
 [6,] NA                                                 NA                                                NA    
 [7,] NA                                                 NA                                                NA    
 [8,] "103 ,ose\r\a"                                     "\r\a"                                            NA    
 [9,] "241,272\r1 .225\r1 ,225\r\a"                      "\r\a"                                            NA    
[10,] "43,739\rEE,E03\r\a"                               "1 ,300\r1 ,300\r\a"                              NA    
[11,] "2CC,E24\r\a"                                      "71 *590\r\a"                                     NA    
[12,] "24,E97\r252,718\r\a"                              "56 ,973\r44,557\r173,120\r615 .77B\r615,778\r\a" NA
```